# collision detection / hitTest in easeljs

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I am currently making a E-learning web page. I am trying to add functionality where user can drag a text and place it on some droppable area/image.

How can I detect drop/hittest in easeljs.

Plz help. I am new to this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `hitTest` method in a [`DisplayObject`](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html) class that checks if a `Point` (in *local* coordinates) is inside.
However:

> Shape-to-shape collision is not currently supported by EaselJS.

So you can either check if your dragging point intersects with the target, or write a custom hit test function.

Comment: Here is a quick sample showing point-based and basic shape-to-shape collision: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/0u7zmjhg/